# Table View paging only on header

Tags: ios, uitableview

I have created a tableview with a header that is the size of the screen:

```
CGRect headerFrame = [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds;
```

I also enabled paging. However, I only want the paging to happen between the header and the first table cell. Any solutions?

Answer (score 0):

You can insert UIScrollView in UITable HeaderView and enable paging.